# Detecting on which CCSprite has been clicked

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-x, ccsprite, cclayer

My main screen is Main.ccbi, it contains 3 CCSprite. Now I want that when user clicks on a CCSprite I should know on which he has clicked?
I want to calculate in CCMotionBegin method that on which CCSprite user has clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First store the sprites you have created in a `CCArray` say `mSpriteArray` and then you can do something like the following

```
bool MyClass :: ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCPoint currentTouchLocation = pTouch->getLocationInView();
    currentTouchLocation = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(currentTouchLocation);
    currentTouchLocation = this->convertToNodeSpace(currentTouchLocation);

    CCSprite *selectedSprite = getSpriteAtPosition(currentTouchLocation);

    return true;
}

CCSprite* MyClass :: getSpriteAtPosition(CCPoint inTouchPosition)
{
    CCObject *object;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(mSpriteArray, object)
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)sprite;

        if (sprite->boundingBox().containsPoint(inTouchPosition))
        {
            return sprite;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Hope this helps.